Need to size buttons to be bigger on phone and smaller on desktop
I'm creating a simple webpage that just has a logo and buttons centered in the middle of the page. This is just a simple directory to our other sites and pages:
The issue I'm running into is that everything is too small when I view on my phone.  I'm basically want the logo and buttons large enough on my phone so it resembles an app but also just normal-sized buttons on a desktop (even though there will be alot of white space around the buttons, which is fine).
I've been trying to use a number of things including the @media only rule sized for desktop and smaller when viewed on a phone and vice versa.
Does anyone know what CSS I can use to get this to work?
Page:
https://flotronicsautomation.com/flotronics-links-page.html
Current CSS:
https://flotronicsautomation.com/css/faci-styles.css

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

The CSS Link seems like it may be getting cut off;  Here the rest at the bottom of the sheet if its not showing up:

This question is similar to: Responsive css styles on mobile devices ONLY. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The solution is actually in HTML, not CSS. Add this line into the <head> section of your HTML. Read more about it here.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

This statement declares that your site has been mobile-optimised. Without it, mobile browsers treat your site as a desktop site, with a much wider viewport and everything zoomed way out.

Brett,  Thanks for this info.  I added this line to the head of the HTML pages and got rid of all the @media lines in the CSS.  It made everything big on both my phone and the desktop.  So it's a step in the right direction for the phone but a step in the opposite direction for the desktop.  I've been trying to change the CSS and other aspects to control the size of the buttons both on the desktop view and the phone view and nothing seems to be changing.  How do I set this up where it's still a normal size on a desktop, large on a mobile view, and able to adjust the button sizes?

At the moment your buttons are styled with width: 80%. So on a desktop, that's enormous. A better setup would be set the standard (desktop) width of your buttons using px or em units, plus add a maximum width in % units to handle the mobile. Something like this: width: 18em; padding: 0.5em; max-width: 80%;

Thanks Brett.  I appreciate the help.  I found this video which is also helping me to understand all this better:
https:// https://youtu.be/UUjNEMXZA-k
